# React Hooks, Conditionally change state inside onClick function, updates on the next click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I have a single list component which render some `<Card>` components that has a `prop` `isSelected` . Because alot of things happens when a `<Card>` Component has `isSelected === true` I added the `state` on the `<List>` component, and I want when someone clicks a card to check:

1) If there are no previously selected items ( `state===null` to add that item's id to state )

2) If someone clicks the same item or another item while there is already an item selected in state, to just unselected the active item.

```
import {Card} from "./Card";
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

const List = () => {
    const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(null);

    const onCardClick = id => {
        console.debug(selectedCard, id)
        const newSelectedCard = cloneDeep(selectedCard);
        // if he clicks another item while an item is active
        // or if he clicks the same item while active
        // should just make it inactive
        if (newSelectedCard !== null || newSelectedCard === id) {
            setSelectedCard(null)
        } else {
            setSelectedCard(id)
        }
        console.debug(selectedCard, id)
    }

    return (
        <ul className="card-list">
            {cardData.map(card => (
                <Card
                    onClick={() => onCardClick(card.id)}
                    key={card.id}
                    isSelected={selectedCard === card.id}
                    {...card}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}


export const CardList = () => (
    <List/>
);
```

The issue is that the 2 `console.debugs` print the same values which means that the state doesnt update imediately and Im experiencing some strange behaviours here and there. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to follow 3 condition as below

```
if(newSelectedCard === null){
        setSelectedCard(id)
    }
    else if(newSelectedCard === id){
        setSelectedCard(null);
    }
    else{
        setSelectedCard(id)
    }
```

**Here is the Complete example:**

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import React, {useState} from "react";

const List = () => {
    const [cardData, setCardData] = useState([
        {id: 1, title: 'First Card'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Second Card'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Third Card'},
        {id: 4, title: 'Fourth Card'},
    ]);
    const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(null);

    const onCardClick = id => {
        console.log(selectedCard, id);
        const newSelectedCard = cloneDeep(selectedCard);
        // if he clicks another item while an item is active
        // or if he clicks the same item while active
        // should just make it inactive
        if(newSelectedCard === null){
            setSelectedCard(id)
        }
        else if(newSelectedCard === id){
            setSelectedCard(null);
        }
        else{
            setSelectedCard(id)
        }
        console.log(selectedCard, id)
    };

    return (
        <ul className="card-list">
            {cardData.map(card => (
                <Card
                    onClick={() => onCardClick(card.id)}
                    key={card.id}
                    isSelected={selectedCard === card.id}
                    {...card}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
};

export const CardList = () => (
    <List/>
);

const Card = (props) => {
    const backColor = props.isSelected? '#F9740E' : '#3FB566';
    return (
        <div onClick={() => props.onClick()}>
            <div style={{backgroundColor: backColor, border: '1px solid darkgreen', color: 'white', padding: 10, marginBottom: 10}}>
                <h3>{props.id}</h3>
                <h4>{props.title}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Update**
[Here is Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/card-list-selection-example-he1cx)

Comment: Nothing changed. I think that I should somehow add that function inside a useEffect but cant understand the proper way

Comment: Hi, It is working, Please see the link of `code sandbox` in the update section on last of my answer

Comment: You are right. Although on my end it was still console loging the same output on both instances. I will need to recheck it when Im home if I had anything different.

Comment: I dont know whats happening. I commented my whole code and added yours and I still getting the same print from both console.logs : https://imgur.com/a/KAwz7pR

Comment: hi, I checked my code sandbox again and everything is fine. not sure what happened in your side. it is very hard to identify without seeing anything. Please check your code very carefully. hope there is any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to use cloneDeep.

```
const onCardClick = id => {
   if (selectedCard === id) {
       setSelectedCard(null);
   } else {
       setSelectedCard(id);
   }
}
```

Comment: I was using an object as state before, and I forgot to remove it. Although removing cloneDeep doesnt change anything at all ^^

Comment: try using await before setSelectedCard(id);